# Large, small but a useful number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, big-list, big-numbers

Today we were discussing in our class about usefulness of a number no problem how large,small  may be it's value. As per my knowledge (till grade 11) [Avogadro number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) $N_A=6.022\times 10^{23}$ is a very useful number while G=$6.67\times 10^{-11}$ is small but useful in physics. But I don't know if there exists a number far larger than what I mentioned but used in real life. Note $\infty$ isn't of my  interest .

Comment: Those are not just numbers, but physical constants with _dimensions_. That means the value is arbitrary: it depends on what _units_ you are using

Comment: @LuisMendo Avogadro's number is arguably dimensionless.

Comment: Oops. I forgot about that one @Omnomnomnom

Comment: [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) is usually the go-to example here, but higher numbers have since been made useful.

Comment: [Here's a video of Ron Graham](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HX8bihEe3nA) explaining his number

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ... although Avogadro's number is a count, the quantity you counting up to depends on an arbitrary choice of mass scale.

Comment: @Joffan hence "arguably"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yes, I just was adding a bit of arguing to show how right you were :-)

Comment: Another topic that may be of interest here is the notion of "infinitely small, but non-zero" numbers (i.e. dual numbers, hyperreal numbers, and surreal numbers).

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia has a few [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers#Other_large_numbers_used_in_mathematics_and_physics).

[Here is Graham himself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HX8bihEe3nA) explaining what Graham's number expresses. (It's an upper bound for an geometric problem).

It has been constructed to make a proof work so it's not a arbitrary construct. However I'm not sure if you would still consider this as "used in real life".

It's large enough that you can't express it in a regular notation.